Opening an external link deletes authentication Cookie on the target page
I have an Angular application, where user can click on a link and gets redirected to another website. This website has a SameSite=Strict cookie set to authenticate. The first time, the user clicks the external link and needs to login. I would expect then that all the next times the user clicks on our external link, it won't need to re-authenticate on the other website. But actually, when the link is clicked, the cookie disappears.
This is pretty painful for the end user as it needs to login everytime.
I have found some interesting things:

If the user navigate to the external website by himself, and logs in, everything works. The user can open a new tab and paste the same url and it will be logged in. He can reload the page and he will be logged in.
If the user navigates to the external website by clicking the link in our platform, the cookie will disappear. Moreover:

if the user logs in and reloads the same page, the cookie gets deleted again!
To keep the login, the user needs to copy the url in another tab by himself, and then login. This way it will not be logged out.
In case the link on our platform is clicked again, the cookie will be deleted again for every tab open.



So, why a simple href is deleting this cookie and how can I solve this?

are you sure the cookie is deleted?  (It should still be there, but it's not sent unless origin is the same...)

workaround would be to set that site's cookie to same-site lax.  This would loosen security against CSRF attacks.

I cannot set the cookie to Lax because I do not have control over the other application.

I do not understand why linking to a page would lose the cookies. Even if the cookie is Strict, I am just only clicking on an external link. This will open a new tab that will load the other website. What is so different than manually opening a tab and pasting the url?

it's a cross-domain request.  Setting same-site strict helps protect against CSRF attacks.

OK so I guess I cannot do this, since I have no control on the other site cookies. Will need to do it in another way.
